# Large CSV is being loaded much slower than expected, could it be that the RAM Python is allowed to use is limited?

Tags: python, ram

I'm trying to load a large CSV file into a pandas dataframe. The CSV is rather large: a few GB.

The code is working, but rather slowly. Slower than I would expect it to even. If I take only 1/10th of the CSV, the job is done in about 10 seconds. If I try to load the whole file, it takes more than 15 minutes. I would expect this to just take roughly 10 times as long, not ~100 times.

The amount of RAM used by python is never above exactly 1,930.8 MB (there is 16GB in my system):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5NpC.png)

It seems to be capped at this, making me think that there is some sort of limit on how much RAM python is allowed to use. However, I never set such a limit and online everyone says "Python has no RAM limit".

Could it be that the RAM python is allowed to use is limit somewhere? And if so, how do I remove that limit?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You could play with `chunksize` and `engine` parameters at least if you are using the regular `read_csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not just how much RAM it can use, but *how fast is your CPU*. Loading very large csv file is very time-consuming if you just use plain `pandas`. Here are a few options:

- You can try other libraries that are made to work with big data. [This tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rohanrao/tutorial-on-reading-large-datasets) shows some libraries. I like `dask`. Its API is like `pandas`.
- If you have GPU, you can use `rapids` (which is also mentioned in the link). Man, `rapids` is really a game changer. Any computation on GPU is just significantly faster. One drawback is that not all features in `pandas` are yet implemented, but that's if you need them.
- The last solution, although not recommended, is you can process your file in batches, e.g., use a `for` loop, load only the first 100K rows, process them, save, then continue doing so until the file ends. This is still very time-consuming but that's the most naive way.

I hope it helps.